# 3-state toggle switch in an ember-light-table

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components

I’m new working with Ember.js and ember-light-table. What I’m looking to do is have a three state toggle switch in one of the columns of my table. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/MbR6c/) of the type of toggle switch I’m talking about. At this point I can render the toggle switch in the correct column, however, only the first toggle box works. What’s the best ‘ember approach’ to solving this type of issue? I assume you build a component so I did, look at the component and the controller for the table which calls the component in the correct column. What's the best approach to get data out of these toggle switches and into a controller so I can update my database?

Update: I'm still struggling with the same issue, but I've gotten closer now. I can get the 'id' of the row when I click a button. What I need to do is query the store for the correct 'row' from the table. I've tride 'this.get('store').peekRecord('model', id ); where id would be the Id I got from clicking the button.

Controller

```
//app/controller/table.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import Table from 'ember-light-table';

const computed = Ember.computed;

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  toggleIds: [],
  model: [],
  table: null,

  actions: {
    updateModel: function() {
      const store = this.get('store');

      const users = store.peekAll('user');
      console.log("user store: ", users);
    },

    onColumnClick(column) {
      console.log('onColumnClick', column );
    }
  },

  columns: computed(function() {
    return [{
      label: 'Home Team',
      valuePath: 'HomeTeam',
      align: 'center'
    }, {
      label: 'Away Team',
      valuePath: 'AwayTeam',
      align: 'center'
    }, {
      label: 'Score',
      valuePath: 'score',
      align: 'center'
    }, {
      label: 'Winner,
      valuePath: 'winner',
      align: 'center'
    }, {
      label: 'Select',
      align: 'center',
      sortable: false,
      cellComponent: 'toggle-switch' // <-- compnent called here!
    }];
  }),

  setupTable() {
    console.log("got here: ", this.get('model') );
    this.set('table', new Table(this.get('columns'), this.get('model')));
  }

});
```

Component - Updated

```
// app/templates/components/toggle-switch.hbs

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default" {{action tableActions.toggleAway row.id }}>
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Away
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" checked> @
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default" {{action tableActions.toggleHome row.id }}>
    <input  type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Home
  </label>
</div>
```

table.hbs

```
  {{#light-table table tableClassNames="table table-striped table-hover"
      tableActions=(hash
        toggleHome=(action 'toggleHome')
        toggleAway=(action 'toggleAway')
      ) as |t|}}

  {{t.head
    onColumnClick=(action 'onColumnClick')
    iconAscending='fa fa-sort-asc'
    iconDescending='fa fa-sort-desc'
    resizeOnDrag=true
  }}

  {{#t.body as |body|}}

    {{#if isLoading}}
      {{#body.loader}}
        Loading...
      {{/body.loader}}
    {{/if}}

    {{#if table.isEmpty}}
      {{#body.no-data}}
        No data found.
      {{/body.no-data}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/t.body}}

  {{#t.foot }}
      <tr style="background-color: lightgray">
      <td class="align-center" colspan={{columns.length}}>
        <button {{action "savePicks"}} class="btn btn-success pull-right" style="padding:5px 20px">Save</button>
        <h5 class="pull-left">Current Games</h5>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{/t.foot}}

{{/light-table}}
```

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?